# wlp2s0 with wpa_supplicant under NixOS

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant, nixos

I have a NixOS system (nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-18.03). Using `wpa_supplicant`, I can't get my wireless card to connect to my home network (WPA2).

It's using the new [Systemd Predictable Network Interface Names](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702161/why-is-my-interface-now-wlp2s0-instead-of-wlan0) scheme (`wlp2s0` replaces `wlan0`).

**A)** Following [NixOS Manual / 11.6 Wireless Networks](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-wireless), I set a WPA sid and passphrase.

```
$ wpa_passphrase ESSID PSK > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
$ systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service
```

The `wpa_supplicant` module can be either active

```
$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA Supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/fw6xw11p5nprhbchdgapj54js84zk97l-unit-wpa_supplicant.service/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-03-09 14:40:43 EST; 1min 11s ago
 Main PID: 800 (wpa_supplicant)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
           └─800 wpa_supplicant -s -u -Dnl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlp2s0

Mar 09 14:40:43 nixos systemd[1]: Started WPA Supplicant.
Mar 09 14:40:48 nixos wpa_supplicant[800]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
```

Or loaded, but inactive.

```
$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA Supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/fw6xw11p5nprhbchdgapj54js84zk97l-unit-wpa_supplicant.service/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2019-03-09 12:04:11 EST; 2h 30min ago
  Process: 2017 ExecStart=/nix/store/77cvdnjyb1djvirr61591ipgnm6nx9mx-unit-script/bin/wpa_supplicant-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2017 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 09 11:59:03 nixos systemd[1]: Started WPA Supplicant.
Mar 09 11:59:03 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Mar 09 12:04:11 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: nl80211: Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/p2p-dev-wlp2s0/drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast: No such file or directo>
Mar 09 12:04:11 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: nl80211: Failed to set IPv4 unicast in multicast filter
Mar 09 12:04:11 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: nl80211: Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/p2p-dev-wlp2s0/drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast: No such file or directo>
Mar 09 12:04:11 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: nl80211: Failed to set IPv4 unicast in multicast filter
Mar 09 12:04:11 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Mar 09 12:04:11 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
Mar 09 12:04:11 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Mar 09 12:04:11 nixos wpa_supplicant[2017]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

Either way, I still can't ping a web address.

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

enp0s20f0u2  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

**B)** I also played around with manually setting the SSID and passphrase. But no dice.

```
$ iwlist wlp2s0 scan
$ iwconfig wlp2s0 essid <mysid> key s:<mypassphrase>
```

**C)** I dug around the internets, and found people with similar issues. But those solutions don't work for me (bring down, flush, up wlp2s0, rebind with wpa_supplicant).

```
$ ip link set dev wlp2s0 down
$ ip addr flush dev wlp2s0
$ ip link set dev wlp2s0 up
$ wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp2s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Could not set interface 'p2p-dev-wlp2s0' UP
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
```

- [Wlan with wpa_supplicant under NixOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/937059/wlan-with-wpa-supplicant-under-nixos)
- [“killall wpa_supplicant” affects “ip route add …” in a strange way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195871/killall-wpa-supplicant-affects-ip-route-add-in-a-strange-way)
- [Unable to connect to wifi with wpa_supplicant](https://superuser.com/questions/487949/unable-to-connect-to-wifi-with-wpa-supplicant)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved @Nutritioustim?

Comment: @tcelferact In this particular case, I had to buy a different router (unrelated issue). Turns out that the new router works fine with my NixOS box. I'm sure there was an underlying issue there. But I never pursued it after that.